# Deactivate Account on Vita and use same memory card for another PSN account

Tags: psn, ps-vita

I have a memory card I have been using with my account. Is it possible to deactivate and format my memory card, and set it up for another PSN account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

First, follow the [deactivation steps](http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6805#How) to deactivate the account (this is optional and can be done in a PC later on, but it's quicker to do it in the console).
Then, go to Settings > Format > Reset the PS Vita System.
After the system is reset and formatted, you can set up another account on it.